# How to copy Access Database File?

Tags: c#, .net, file-copying

I want to copy existing Acccess Database file from my project into another location using SaveFileDialog in C#.

I wrote following code segments:

```
SaveFileDialog s = new SaveFileDialog();
s.Title = "SaveFile As...";
s.Filter = "Access Documents (*.accdb)|*.accdb|Others Documents (*.*)|*.*;";

string filenames = "MyAccDB.accdb";
s.FileName = filenames;

if (s.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
{
   File.Copy(@"MyAccDB.accdb", s.FileName);
}
```

But it doesn't work and not saving.
How can I save access DB file into another location?

Comment: You'll have to provide quite a bit more info.  For example, exactly what does "it doesn't work" mean.  Do you get an error, if so which one?  That method throws 8 different messages depending on the problem...  Also, the framework version might help.

Comment: it doesn't work mean,my database file wasn't save new locations.

Comment: Was an exception thrown?  If so, which one?

Answer (score 4):

Give full path. See examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa328773%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).

```
File.Copy(@"C:\...\MyAccDB.accdb", @"C:\...\MyAccDB.accdb");
```

Comment: @CSharpCrasy : Glad to help! Please select the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just simple,

```
File.Copy("Source file Path","Destination file path)";
```

That's all.